# How do I script a "yes" response for installing programs when I already use echo "password" to auto pass the authentication

Tags: perl, elasticsearch, plugins

I found that it is useful to use     "yes | command-that-asks-for-input"
to automatically key in yes during installation. However, I also need to auto pass the authentication of sudo. So my current perl script is:

```
system "echo \"$password\" | sudo -S /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/plugin install file://$localDepDir/plugins/$licensename";
```

How can I still able to key in "yes" when using the code above?? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
system "( echo \"$password\" ; yes ) | sudo -S ..."
```

Note that it can break (same as the original code) if the password contains a double quote, dollar sign etc.